# django dynamic inclusion tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-filter

I'm trying to add some image gallery to the template but position of the gallery on the page need to be defined by user. Sometimes it will be at the top of the text, sometimes at the end and sometimes at the middle of the text on the page. In the text field user will add this line `#foto` and based on the position of the that line I need to render gallery. For example:

```
some paragraph written by user in the text field...

#foto

some another paragraph written by user ...
```

Now the easiest way will be to replace `#foto` with include tag in the view. Something as :

```
foto = "{% include 'includes/gallery.html' %}"
xx = "#foto"
post.text = post.text.replace(xx, foto)
```

But this example doesn't work because include tag can't be call on that way. It is rendered as pure text {% include 'includes/gallery.html' %}. What can be done to render include tag as expected on the position of the `#foto` text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign foto the rendered template, inside your view:

```
...
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
"""
Get the items from the model, define your query
"""
gallery = GalleryModel.objects.all()
"""
Render gallery template and assign to foto, which then you
can inject in the basic template
"""
foto = render_to_string('includes/gallery.html', {'gallery': gallery})
...
```

then in your template:

```
{{ foto }}
```

Comment: No petkostas gallery can't be call on that way {{ post.text }} is a tag which return text and gallery need to be on the position of the ` #foto ` word in the text.

Comment: So implement the above and replace the text as in your original post, the render_to_string is what you are looking for.
Fetch the post.text, do your replacement with the foto rendered template.